# Win key replayed when focus changes from Windows to Ubuntu host

Tags: synergy, ubuntu-unity

I'm running the [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) server (version 1.3.6) on an Ubuntu 11.10 host and the client (version 1.3.8) on a Windows 7 host.

Whenever I use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key on the windows client, they key is somehow "replayed" on my Ubuntu server the moment the mouse focus returns to the host (which triggers the dash home). This happens even if there is a long delay between the keypress and the focus change, or if other keys were entered before the focus change.

The opposite does not happen - when I use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key on the ubuntu server it is not replayed when I shift the focus to the Windows client.

Any ideas why this is happening? Can I stop this from happening?

#### Update:

I've just notices that when I hold down the <kbd>Win</kbd> key while the focus is on the client machine (Win 7), the Unity bar on the host machine (Ubuntu 11.10) also gets triggered! It looks as though Unity is also trapping the keypress even as Synergy sends it to the client.

When I change the hotkey for Unity to something else, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the same thing happens - using that key on the client will also trigger the Unity bar on the host.

It looks like Unity is *stealing* keypress events; this problem is not unique to synergy but also happens when running [VMs such as VirtualBox and VMWare](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70177). Relevant bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/780803
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/704231
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/806255
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/741869

Comment: Updates: [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/741869) is now marked as having "high importance" and a fix is scheduled for [Compiz 0.9.9.2](https://launchpad.net/compiz/+milestone/0.9.9.2).

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but a possible workaround. Does this happen only if you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+something (e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) or also if <kbd>Win</kbd> alone?

If it's e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can do it two ways:

1. press <kbd>Win</kbd>, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, release <kbd>Tab</kbd>, release <kbd>Win</kbd>
2. press <kbd>Win</kbd>, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, release <kbd>Win</kbd>, release <kbd>Tab</kbd>

I noticed similar artifacts in various remote desktop applications if I use the first way. However, if I release the modifier (<kbd>Win</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) first and the effect (in above example, <kbd>Tab</kbd>) second then there are no artifacts.

Hope this helps.